# Can't re-add Service Reference Properly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, service-reference

I've got a WCF service up and running on a server. We have a proxy class that we add all service references to, and I tried to add my service reference there. However, it's not exposing all of the methods, specifically the interface, allowing me to create an instance of it (this is VS 2008). However, when I create a new project, and just add the service reference to it, it adds all of the interfaces properly.

Any ideas on how to force the original project to re-add the project properly? Is there something in memory that is not getting cleared? I've tried deleting the reference, rebuilding, closing and re-opening the project, but it still comes out the same way.

I've also tried deleting the project and re-creating it with no luck there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It turns out that if you don't add all the necessary references to the project, then the references needing them will not appear. It turned out that we needed to add System.Drawing as a reference, and then the solution added fine. I wish there was some feedback about this from MS, but if anyone runs into something like this in the future, just remember, you need to add all references...